# turning function to occur every 5 seconds instead of every button click

Tags: javascript, html, time, intervals

Need to have the below code work every 5 second instead of every button click (language: html):

```
<script>
function goFwd(e) {
  reset();
  if (e.target.classList.contains("next") && currentImage < thumbnails.length-1) {
    currentImage += 1;
    fullSizeImgs[currentImage].classList.add('show');
    caption.textContent = thumbnails[currentImage].firstElementChild.getAttribute('alt');
    hiLiteThumbnail(); 
  } else if (e.target.classList.contains("next") && currentImage === thumbnails.length-1) {
    currentImage = 0;
    fullSizeImgs[currentImage].classList.add('show');
    caption.textContent = thumbnails[currentImage].firstElementChild.getAttribute('alt');
    hiLiteThumbnail();  
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What language is this? On what OS? You should always add a language tag when asking a question related to code. It helps get the question in front of the people who might be able to answer it, and it helps it to be found in searches by users in the future who are trying to find a problem solution. Please [edit] your post to add a tag for that programming language; there's an edit link just below the tags in the lower left corner of your post.

Comment: Hi Ken, it's html

Comment: Then [edit] your post and add a HTML tag, as I asked twice in my previous comment.

Comment: I put <script> and </script> ... this is a javascript code, i don't think that html codes will help here ...

Comment: i'm a bignner, i'm trying to get you, I already added JS code, i don't want to elongate the question for fear that it may not be answered

Comment: already added a while ago ...

Comment: THere is still no Javascript tag on your post. Tags are in the lower left corner of your question, across from your avatar. Your post shows *time* and *intervals* tags, but NO JAVASCRIPT TAG. Your post text says *language: html*, which is not only wrong but unnecessary if you ADD THE JAVASCRIPT TAG. Now I've asked **seven times**.

Comment: @Botros Wadie: There was probably some confusion here, what Ken White meant was not to add an HTML tag like `<div>` but to add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) (we also have tags and they are a different thing) to the post with the language, in this case `javascript`. The question tags are the field _below_ the question text. Such a tag is important because it influences which people see your question in their feed. (This time someone else [did it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62843636/revisions) but it would be great if you could do it yourself next time.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use javascript to make the loop with 5 seconds.

```
<script>

window.setInterval(function(){
    goFwd(e)
}, 5000);

</script>
```

when you want to stop the loop you can use: clearInterval()

### Updated

You can make the button auto click after 5 seconds. Then your function will call automatically after every 5 seconds.

```
<script>

var btn = document.getElementById('your_button_id');
setInterval(function(){
    btn.click();
}, 5000);  // this will make it click again every 5 seconds

</script>
```

Comment: I get the below error:   Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    <anonymous> file:///F:/JavaScript/Sponsers/Galleria.html:402
Galleria.html:402:24

Comment: You should put e in the function(): function(e)

Comment: again not working:   Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined
    goFwd file:///F:/JavaScript/Sponsers/Galleria.html:366
    <anonymous> file:///F:/JavaScript/Sponsers/Galleria.html:388
Galleria.html:366:7
    goFwd file:///F:/JavaScript/Sponsers/Galleria.html:366
    <anonymous> file:///F:/JavaScript/Sponsers/Galleria.html:388

Comment: @BotrosWadie, I added another solution, you can check it.